# How to Define a Horizontal Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

I realize this is probably a silly question but I'm going to have to ask it anyways:  how would I define a complex function so that is a perfect horizontal line, perpendicular to the $iy$ axis and of course never touching the $x$ axis?

Let's let $y=c$ where $c$ is a non-zero constant.  Then is my function $z=0x+ic=ic$, similar to how we might make a horizontal function between two real axes?  Or is it $z=x+ic$?

Sorry, having a bad math day.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parametrize the line as $z=x+ic \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\,$, or write its complex equation as $z-\bar z=2ic\,$.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what all signs seemed to indicate.  Just curious though if you might know - what shape function would $z=ic$ create?  Would it just be a point where $z=ic, x=0x=0$, and $iy=ic$?

Comment: @greycatbird Right, $\,z=ic\,$ would be just that single point. Same goes for $\,z=z_0\,$ for any fixed $\,z_0 \in \mathbb{C}\,$. That's similar to how $\,x=x_0, y=y_0\,$ defines one single point in cartesian coordinates.